# Images hover-over not working on a couple of images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ive got a fully workin site at http://www.innexdesign.co.uk. On the homepage you'll notice some hover-over words that appear black when you hover over them. Ive implemented this existing site made in Dreamweaver over to Umbraco the .net based CMS.

Anyway ive got the site up and running but for some stange reason two of the images "Architecture" and "Energy Assessments" arent hovering black anymore. The rest still work fine.

```
    <div id="content">
<div id="homeleft">
    <ul class="menu">
    <li class="first"><a href="home.aspx">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="profile.aspx">PROFILE</a></li>
    <li><a href="designs.aspx">DESIGNS</a></li>
    <li><a href="testimonials.aspx">TESTIMONIALS</a></li>    
    <li class="last"><a href="contact.aspx">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
    <p style="text-align:center; font-weight:bold;">CELEBRATING<br /><span style="font-size:22px">21</span><br />YEARS<br />1991-2012</p>
    </div>
<div id="homeright">
  <a class="various1" href="#architecture" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Architecture','',/Images/architectureBLACK.png',1)"><img src="/Images/architecture.png" alt="Architecture" width="195" height="31" id="Architecture" style="padding:0px 20px;float:left;"/></a>
  <a class="various1" href="#idesign" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('interiordesign','','/Images/interior-designBLACK.png',1)"><img src="/Images/interior-design.png" alt="Interior Design" width="195" height="31" id="interiordesign" style="padding:0px 0px 5px 20px; float:right;"/></a>
  <a class="various1" href="#pmanage" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Projman','','/Images/project-managementBLACK.png',1)"><img src="/Images/project-management.png" alt="Project Managment" width="195" height="31" id="Projman" style="padding:20px 42px 5px 20px;float:left;"/></a>
  <a class="various1" href="#planning" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Planning','','/Images/PlanningBLACK.png',1)"><img src="/Images/Planning.png" alt="Planning" width="195" height="31" id="Planning" style="padding:10px 12px 5px 0px;float:right;"/></a>
  <a class="various1" href="#energy" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Energy Assessment','','/Images/energy-assessmentsBLACK.png',1)"><img src="/Images/energy-assessments.png" alt="Energy Assessments" width="195" height="31" id="EnergyAssessment" style="padding:0px 42px 0px 20px;float:right;"/></a>
  <a class="various1" href="#surveying" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Surveying','','/Images/SurveyingBLACK.png',1)"><img src="/Images/Surveying.png" alt="Surveying" width="195" height="31" id="Surveying" style="padding:10px;float:left;" /></a>
  <a class="various1" href="#cost" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('CostManagement','','/Images/cost-managementBLACK.png',1)"><img src="/Images/cost-management.png" alt="Cost Management" width="195" height="31" id="CostManagement" style="padding:0px 12px 0px 20px; float:left;"/></a>
  <a class="various1" href="#land" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('landscape','','/Images/landscape-architectureBLACK.png',1)"><img src="images/Landscape-Architecture.png" alt="Landscape Architecture" width="195" height="31" id="landscape" style="padding:20px 0px 0px 20px; float:right;" /></a>
  <div id="various1"> <a href="http://www.innexdevelopments.co.uk" target="_blank"  onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('DesignBuild','','/Images/DESIGNANDBUILDBLACK.png',1)"><img src="/Images/DESIGNANDBUILD.png" alt="Design and Build" width="195" height="31" id="DesignBuild" style="padding:10px 0 0 0px;float:left;"/></a>
</div>
<div style="display:none"><div id="architecture">
<img src="/media/52/architecture.png" width="195" height="31" alt="Architecture" />
<p style="padding:0px 0px 5px 0px; width:500px;">From a house extension or housing estate, to commercial warehouses’, leisure centres and bars, Innex Design can help develop any idea into a practical, ethical, sustainable reality.</p>    
</div></div>

<div style="display:none"><div id="idesign">
<img src="/media/441/interior-design.png" width="195" height="31" alt="Interior Design" />
<p style="padding:0px 0px 5px 0px; width:500px;">Innex Design’s Interior and brand development designers are experts in spatial design, brand development and awareness, signage and menu design all of which is complimented with the interior design package delivered.</p>    
</div></div>
<div style="display:none"><div id="pmanage">
<img src="/media/727/project-management.png" width="195" height="31" alt="Project Management" />
<p style="padding:0px 0px 5px 0px; width:500px;">Many of our architectural and interior design developments are project managed ensuring the brief and end aim is delivered on time and on budget. Only with project management can we ensure our clients that the specification and quality is to the highest standard.</p>
</div></div>
<div style="display:none"><div id="planning">
<img src="/media/709/Planning.png" width="195" height="31" alt="Planning" />
<p style="padding:0px 0px 5px 0px; width:500px;">Innex Design undertake all planning application submissions from residential, commercial, listed and conservation area consents, national park along with Display of Advertisement applications. We also work with planning consultants to add value for developers and lenders by assessing land and building use potential.</p>
</div></div>
<div style="display:none"><div id="energy">
<img src="/media/328/energy-assessments.png" width="195" height="31" alt="Energy Assessments" />
<p style="padding:0px 0px 5px 0px; width:500px;">Innex Design can assist with providing full building services design and energy consultancy, and through one of our partners BREEAM assessment, Commercial EPC, Domestic EPC, Display energy certificates, New Build SAP or SBEM reports and Sustainability statements.</p>
</div></div>
<div style="display:none"><div id="surveying">
<img src="/media/917/Surveying.png" width="195" height="31" alt="Surveying" />
<p style="padding:0px 0px 5px 0px; width:500px;">Innex Design can provide a wide variety of surveys from measured and condition surveys of buildings, Topographical surveys, Structural surveys, Party Wall surveys, and provide assistance with Asbestos surveys, Land/Probate surveys, certification and many more.</p>
</div></div>

<div style="display:none"><div id="cost">
<img src="/media/248/cost-management.png" width="195" height="31" alt="Cost Management" />
<p style="padding:0px 0px 5px 0px; width:500px;">Innex Design offer all clients a comprehensive service that removes the burden of day to day costs-related issues.</p>
</div></div>
<div style="display:none"><div id="land">
<img src="/media/501/Landscape-Architecture.png" width="195" height="31" alt="Landscape Architecture" />
<p style="padding:0px 0px 5px 0px; width:500px;">We undertake all aspects of landscape architecture, from landscape master planning, conceptual design through to detailed planting schemes. We adopt a fresh approach to the design of each project where a high degree of design flair and innovation comes as standard. </p>
</div></div>
<div style="display:none"><div id="build">
<img src="/Images/DESIGNANDBUILD.png" width="195" height="31" alt="Design and Build" />
<p style="padding:0px 0px 5px 0px; width:500px;">In today’s industry and marketplace some clients prefer a one point of contact approach to projects, with this in mind we have developed a nationwide network of partnering contractors to enable clients to have the one point contact, whilst ensuring delivery of excellent quality and standards of workmanship.</p>
</div></div>
  </div>
</div><!-- end content -->
</div><!-- end wrapper -->
```

Any idea why its doing this all of a sudden?

So these two lines:

```
<a class="various1" href="#architecture" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Architecture','',/Images/architectureBLACK.png',1)"><img src="/Images/architecture.png" alt="Architecture" width="195" height="31" id="Architecture" style="padding:0px 20px;float:left;"/></a>

<a class="various1" href="#energy" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Energy Assessment','','/Images/energy-assessmentsBLACK.png',1)"><img src="/Images/energy-assessments.png" alt="Energy Assessments" width="195" height="31" id="EnergyAssessment" style="padding:0px 42px 0px 20px;float:right;"/><
```

/a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a mistake in the path to the images since the folder structure is case sensitive. Instead of

```
MM_swapImage('Energy Assessment','','/Images/energy-assessmentsBLACK.png',1)
```

please try

```
MM_swapImage('Energy Assessment','','/images/energy-assessmentsBLACK.png',1)
```

(Notice the uncapitalized 'i' in 'images)

EDIT:

Also your ID given in the call is wrong, the ID of the IMG element is 'EnergyAssessment' not 'Energy Assessment':

```
MM_swapImage('EnergyAssessment','','/images/energy-assessmentsBLACK.png',1)
```

Comment: I have tried that its just my Umbraco folder "Images" is named with a capital I. However i will try updating all instances to lower case i and see what i get. Cheers

Comment: @DiViS0R,Correct! +1. The ID should not have a space in it.

Comment: Yes brilliant thats worked mate. Energy Assessment now hovers black. Still, "Architecture" doesnt hover black and i cant see anything wrong with that. The ID matches the image element does it not?

Comment: @LeeBell Please see my answer below and see if that fixes things for you.

Answer (score 0):

DiViS0R is right about the Energy Assesment error as for the 'Architecture' you are missing a speech mark in the function call after the second comma

```
MM_swapImage('Architecture','',/Images/architectureBLACK.png',1)
```

Should be this by the looks of your other code

```
MM_swapImage('Architecture','','/Images/architectureBLACK.png',1)
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Fantastic spot. Need a keen eye for detail to keep up with this coding lark by the looks of it. Thanks all :)